# how to query data in a fast way after table splitting?

Tags: mysql, large-data

I have a MySQL table about 1000 million records. It is very slow when I make a query.
So I split this table by ID into 10 sub-tables with the same structrue.

```
table_1(1-1000000)

table_2(10000001-2000000)

table_3(20000001-3000000)
......
```

But how can i query data in a fast way after table splitting?

when I query a user like this: `select name from table where name='mark'`, I don't know go to which table for querying beacuse I can get the ID range.

Comment: by checking the range. Have you already tried indexes?

Comment: try Partitioning (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html), it does it all. For the split that you've done, you first need to check which table you need to query depending on ID and then run a query on that table. By the way, as "Mitch Wheat" suggested, did you try indexes on your original table with 1000 million records?

Comment: @Abhay the records is increasing every day, so store all the records in one table is not helpfull. Query problem like this:"select name from table where name='mark'", I don't know go to which table for querying beacuse I can get the range of ID.

Comment: @mitch-wheat, this table is increasing at a fast way, so just add indexes is not a good solution.

Comment: @@xiaochong0302: care to explain why not?

Comment: @mitch-wheat, thank you for your fast response, this large table increase very fast, it will be over 10 million after some months, mysql can not response fast when users send query.

Comment: yep: that's what indexes are for: improving query speed.

Comment: @MitchWheat, do you have any sugguestion on querying after table sharding, the problem is not how to split table, but query after splitting.

Comment: @xiaochong0302, I would suggest that if your table is increasing so fast, you should have some purging logic in place, if possible, because otherwise even the splitted tables will go very huge in some time. By the way, did you look into partitioning?

Comment: @xiaochong0302, you are querying the table on NAME but you are splitting on ID. So there is no way to know which table to query unless you know the ID <=> NAME mapping. Instead, I would suggest you split on NAME, alphabetically perhaps. So, table_A contains all names starting with A, table_B contains all names starting with B. You may even group certain less-common alphabets like table_UVWXYZ contains all names starting with U, V, W, X, Y or Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting tables this way is totally not the right way when you show your example query. You created more issues actually than solving anything.

Let's get back to the big table:

**Step 1** is to see why it is slow, so post explain sql command to get an overview.

**Step 2** is to see whether you can improve that query. Stating things like indexes are not a good solution can be true. If so please provide measurements showing this.

**Step 3** is to think outside the box. You are running queries in a very big table which gets constantly inserts. Consider using a specifically for search designed index. For example consider indexing with Solr for the search commands.

Eventually you might even get to the hardware point, it just can't get faster on this hardware. But first follow through steps, add the right information, concrete measurements and specifications so you can get even more complete support on your case.